# Including dictionary terms with spaces

Tags: autocompletion

We can use dictionaries to help us complete keywords. To set a new dictionary you can use `set dictionary+=path/to/dict`. This way you will be able to complete from a dictionary by typing `<C-x><C-k>` in Insert mode; and then use `<C-n>` or `<C-p>` to browser the suggestions. Moreover, you can `set complete+=k` and now you can type `<C-n>` or `<C-p>` right away.

From `:help 'dictionary'`

> Each file should
>           contain a list of words.  This can be one word per line, or several
>           words per line, separated by non-keyword characters (white space is
>           preferred).

But maybe I would like a term
    `Monty Python`
in my dictionary, such that when I write `Mon` one of the suggestions would be `Monty Python`. The [GNU Miscfiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/miscfiles/) `web2a` is an example of a dicionary in which each line is made up of two words that go together.

Is there a way to include dictionary terms which have spaces?

Comment: I looked at the source code yesterday, and I don't think this is possible, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: It would work with `Mon...`, but think about `Py...` or `Monty Py...`. How would Vim know how many words go backwards to find the beginning of the pattern to look for? I'm not sure, but this might be the reason why it's done this way.

Comment: @xaizek, I see your point. But at least for completing several words (`Monty Python`) when you have just typed part of the first (e.g. `Mon`) there would be no problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if "at least for" is good enough for Bram.  I read some discussions on features that are missing from Vim and they stopped after stating that implementation has limitations similar to this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the source code last week, and I don't think this is possible. As xaizek pointed out in a comment, this would make completion ambiguous.

However, I've thought of a workaround :-) There's the `CompleteDone` autocmd, which is run when:

> After Insert mode completion is done.  Either when something was completed or abandoning completion.

What we can do is write a dictionary not with spaces, but with another character; and use the `CompleteDone` autocmd to replace this character afterwards.

In my example, I use the underscore (`_`). I originally tried to use a more "special" character (such as `·`), but that doesn't seem to work.

An example `dictionary` file looks like:

```
Monty_Python
Monty_Python_Flying_Circus
The_Black_Adder
Captain_Darling
```

And with this `autocmd` the underscores get replaced with spaces; it should be fairly obvious how it works, so I'll not explain that any further:

```
fun! CompleteSpace()
    " Save cursor position
    let l:save_cursor = getpos(".")

    " Get word we just completed ('borrowed' from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23541748/660921)
    let l:word = matchstr(strpart(getline('.'), 0, col('.') - 1), '\k\+$')

    " Replace _ with space
    let l:new = substitute(l:word, "_", " ", "g")

    " Run :s
    exe "s/" . l:word . "/" . l:new . "/e"

    " Restore cursor
    call setpos(".", l:save_cursor)
endfun

if has("patch-7.3-598")
    au CompleteDone * call CompleteSpace()
endif
```

This could perhaps be optimized a bit, but this seems to be 'good enough' for now ;-)

---

## Caveat!

Unfortunately, this autocmd is not perfect, as documented in the `todo.txt` file:

> The CompleteDone autocommand needs some info passed to it:
>   - The word that was selected (empty if abandoned complete)
>   - Type of completion: tag, omnifunc, user func.
>
> [..]
>
> Patch to add v:completed_item. (Shougo Matsu, 2013 Nov 29).

The problem is that it might cause side-effects when completing source code as well; for example `my_variable_name()` gets "fixed" to `my variable name`. The `autocmd` below is for *all* files, you can restrict the autocmd for certain files... There is [actually a patch](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/vim_dev/CompleteDone$20Shougo/vim_dev/fhGAStSCAMg/q5BIr2EcH4YJ) floating around which seems to fix this, but it's not applied yet for whatever reason. Perhaps it's simply forgotten, or maybe it needs some love to fix a minor issue; you could pursue it :-)