# inscompletion: space separated words

Tags: autocompletion

I'd like to use the ins-completion function to suggest not words but WORDS, that is to say, space separated words. Is that possible?

Example: (latex)

```
\mathbb{R}

\ma(Ctrl-n)
```

Comment: Two very related questions: [Including dictionary terms with spaces](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2068/51) and [Ins-completion of WORDs](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/1871/51); duplicate probably?

Comment: I could also suggest continuing with `Ctrl-x Ctrl-n` as many times as needed, after the 1st `Ctrl-n` completion.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll go for abbreviations for commonly inserted text as I do not want to change iskeyword variable, and use c-x c-n for one time completion.

Comment: There's also ^X^L to complete whole lines.

Answer (score 1):

in your example, if you want vim treat `{` and `}` as words, you can use

`set iskeywords+={
set iskeywords+=}`

then you press `<C-N>` the whold `WORDS` will be completed.

see my pic

[image]